# Bind value from on controltemplate to another

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

In my xaml file i have two controls: TextBox and Button.
That controls have their template defined.
Now i want to bind second control's template's TextBlock text value to fisr control's template's TextBlock text value.

How can i do that???

```
<TextBox x:Name="lll">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="CLICK!!!!"></TextBlock>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
        <Button Content="" Margin="25,40,-25,-40">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBlock}}}"></TextBlock>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

Comment: Are you just trying to make a TextBlock clickable? What's your overall goal? Because we'll probably want to do it a different way.

Comment: Can you not simply have a textblock and then a button with its content property bound to the textblock's text property?? Why are you taking the pain of creating a textbox and replacing it with a textblock in its style? And moreover the button's ancestor is not textbox so it is never going to find it in the binding.

Comment: Where is the sense in having a TextBlock in the ControlTemplate of a TextBox? Use the TextBlock directly instead of the TextBox and bind `Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=lll}"`.

Comment: it's just a simple example, i have more complex controls and templates

Answer (score 1):

This code uses Tag of object `lll` to store the text:

```
<TextBox x:Name="lll">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=lll , Path=Tag, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
<Button Content="" Margin="25,40,-25,-40">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=lll, Mode=OneWay, Path=Tag}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```